# Entry on table with GROUP BY and ORDER BY MAX()

Tags: mysql

This code work correctly

```
SELECT
    c.id_article,
    a.titre AS title_article
FROM comments AS c
LEFT JOIN articles AS a
    ON a.id = c.id_article
WHERE c.hide = 0
GROUP BY c.id_article
ORDER BY MAX(c.date) DESC
LIMIT 0, 6
```

But I need the username of last comment in article.

I try this

```
SELECT
    c.id_article,
    a.titre AS title_article,
    u.nom_utilisateur AS user_name
FROM comments AS c
LEFT JOIN articles AS a
    ON a.id = c.id_article
LEFT JOIN membres AS u
    ON c.id_user = u.id
WHERE c.hide = 0
GROUP BY c.id_article
ORDER BY MAX(c.date) DESC
LIMIT 0, 6
```

and not working...

Any help ?

( sorry for my bad english... )

Comment: What not working ? any error ?

Comment: What you want to get? Are you sure comments are in left join with articles? Can a comment be without an article?

Comment: I am trying to retrieve the user name from the last comment posted in the article. My actual function retrieve the last comments from the articles list.

Answer (score 0):

Without the error message or a description what is wrong it is kind of hard to say, but in any case, you did not include `u.nom_utilisateur` in the `GROUP BY` statement.

MySQL often allows this without throwing an error, but it can result in unexpected outcomes.

```
SELECT
    c.id_article,
    a.titre AS title_article,
    u.nom_utilisateur AS user_name
FROM comments AS c
LEFT JOIN articles AS a
    ON a.id = c.id_article
LEFT JOIN membres AS u
    ON c.id_user = u.id
WHERE c.hide = 0
GROUP BY c.id_article, u.nom_utilisateur
ORDER BY MAX(c.date) DESC
LIMIT 0, 6
```

Comment: I am trying to retrieve the user name from the last comment posted in the article.
My actual function retrieve the last comments from the articles list.

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial solution.

I use this code for retrieve the last comments from articles :

```
SELECT
    c.id_article,
    MAX(c.id) AS last_id_comment,
    a.titre AS title_article
FROM comments AS c
LEFT JOIN articles AS a
    ON a.id = c.id_article
WHERE c.hide = 0
GROUP BY c.id_article
ORDER BY MAX(c.date) DESC
LIMIT 0, 6
```

And after in the while for first SELECT i use this code for retrieve the username from the last comment :

```
SELECT
    u.nom_utilisateur AS username
FROM comments AS c
LEFT JOIN membres AS u
    ON u.id = c.id_user
WHERE c.id = :last_id_comment
```

Not the best solution but it's work.